# How to add root node in JSON

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I need to include the top node in my JSON response. My JSON response in REST web service:

```
[
    {
        "address": "delhi",
        "fristname": "xxxx",
        "id": 1,
        "lastname": "xxxx",
        "phone": "0000000"
    },
    {
        "address": "ssss",
        "fristname": "yyyy",
        "id": 2,
        "lastname": "yyyyy",
        "phone": "0000000"
    },
    {
        "address": "wwww",
        "fristname": "aaaa",
        "id": 3,
        "lastname": "aaaaa",
        "phone": "0000000"
    }
]
```

I want JSON response like this:

```
"employee": [
    {
        "address": "delhi",
        "fristname": "xxxx",
        "id": 1,
        "lastname": "xxxx",
        "phone": "0000000"
    },
    {
        "address": "ssss",
        "fristname": "yyyy",
        "id": 2,
        "lastname": "yyyyy",
        "phone": "0000000"
    },
    {
        "address": "wwww",
        "fristname": "aaaa",
        "id": 3,
        "lastname": "aaaaa",
        "phone": "0000000"
    }
]
```

Please tell me how to add root node JSON. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do it like this:
JSONObject myobj = new JSONObject();
myobj.put("employees", <yourarray>);

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this in Java. Create a new JSON object and put your array in it.

```
JSONObject myobj = new JSONObject(); 
myobj.put("employees", <your_json_array>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jackson annotation [JsonRootName](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html):

> Annotation similar to XmlRootElement, used to indicate name to use for
>   root-level wrapping, if wrapping is enabled. Annotation itself does
>   not indicate that wrapping should be used; but if it is, name used for
>   serialization should be name specified here, and deserializer will
>   expect the name as well.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

And annotate your class as follows:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "employee")
public static class Employee {
  private String address;
  private String firstName;
  // more... with getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

  public class Employee
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public int phone { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Samplepage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Employee> eList = new List<Employee>();
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.address = "Minal";
            employee.phone = 24;

            eList.Add(employee);

            employee = new Employee();
            employee.address = "Santosh";
            employee.phone = 24;

            eList.Add(employee);

            string ans = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eList, Formatting.Indented);


            JArray a = JArray.Parse(ans);
            JObject UpdateAccProfile = new JObject(
                               new JProperty("employee", a)
                               );

        }
    }
```